# How eager does LINQ and Entity Framework load by default?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm new to LINQ and the Entity Framework. I've been fetching collections from the database using the following:

```
var Publications = from pubs in db.RecurringPublications
                   select pubs;
```

The Publications table is linked to other tables via foreign keys. I've been using this to reference properties like this:

```
Publications.Single().LinkedTable.LinkedTableColumn
```

and sometimes even further down the chain:

```
Publications.Single().LinkedTable.LinkedTable.LinkedLinkedTableColumn
```

I know you can specify lazy loading or eager loading, I was wondering how it's handled by default. Is there a maximum depth by default? Does it figure out how many joins to use at compile time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only going to eager load what's in that specific table.

```
var Publications = from pubs in db.RecurringPublications
                   select pubs;
```

Will only get the data from your RecurringPublications table.  You can specify if you want to load additional properties, but if you don't specify anything, it will only give you exactly what you ask for - nothing more.

```
Publications.Single().LinkedTable.LinkedTableColumn
```

Is lazy loading your LinkedTableColumn - now if your return is Queryable (and it is so far), it's going to do a join and return a single SQL query.

However, if the call has already been enumerated, it will make a second call.

[Blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx) to MSDN for info

Comment: But what about .LinkedTable.LinkedTable?

Comment: It's the same as above - if it hasn't been Queried, it will do a join across all 3 tables (or any number of tables).  If it has been enumerated, it will do another call for the lazy load.